# Enable Hibernate filter when search by primary/foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, spring-data

I use spring data and hibernate @Filter/@FilterDef to filter soft-deleted entities. It seems like springRepository.findOne(id) always returns value even if id was soft-deleted. Filter is not included in where clause for this method and for searching by another fields which is foreign keys. Is it possible to enable filter in this case so it will work as @Where annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I've solved it by implementing HibernatePersistenceProvider and HibernateEntityManagerFactory classes.

```
public class FilterEnableHibernatePersistenceProvider extends HibernatePersistenceProvider {

    @Override
    public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties) {
        return wrapEntityManagerFactory(super.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName, properties));
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManagerFactory createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map properties) {
        return wrapEntityManagerFactory(super.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(info, properties));
    }

    private EntityManagerFactoryWrapper wrapEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory == null
            ? null
            : new EntityManagerFactoryWrapper(entityManagerFactory);
    }


public static class EntityManagerFactoryWrapper implements HibernateEntityManagerFactory {

    //This is where the filters are being activated
    protected EntityManager initSession(EntityManager entityManager) {
        Session session = ((HibernateEntityManager) entityManager).getSession();
        if (session.getEnabledFilter(FILTER_NAME) == null) {
            Filter activeFilter = session.enableFilter(FILTER_NAME);
            activeFilter.setParameter("some_field", some_value);
        }
        return entityManager;
    }

    // wrapp other methods

}
```

After every session initialization the filter will be enabled. Now you jast need to add FilterEnableHibernatePersistenceProvider to your configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfiguration {

@Bean()
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emFactory.setPersistenceProviderClass(FilterEnableHibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    //yours configuration
}
```