# Hibernate @Filter not filtering foreign key entities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-data-rest and hibernate `@Filter` in order to filter soft-deleted entities. I want to filter soft-deleted entities even if an entity is called by its id in the exposed REST API.

Some of the other solutions I saw and their associated problems are:

1. Using `@Where` clause over the `@OneToMany` (or other mapping) fields to set the `deleted = false`. But I would rather not have any such hard queries in my entity as it will lock me up from querying other things.
2. I have a custom `SoftDeletablePagingSortingQuerydslRepositoryImpl` class which reimplements all the query methods and I can delegate the `findOne` method to `findAll` which should handle filter. But the issue with this is that it is not handling filtering of the foreign keys.
3. I use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091577/enable-hibernate-filter-when-search-by-primary-foreign-keys) but the answer is very old and it doesn't seem to work anymore.

What is the solution to this issue?